# Is there any way to add a css class (brk-preloader)to a html tag specific in one desktop page and mobile for all pages? Eg: wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, class

Here is the sample code, used as a preloader in wordpress.

header.php

```html
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> <?php brk_root_class();?> <?php brk_skin_attr();?>>
```

function.php

```php
/**
 * Root Class
 */
function brk_root_class( $classes = array() ) {

    if ( get_theme_mod( 'brk_preloader', '1' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'brk-preloader';
    }

    if ( is_singular( array( 'brs_header', 'brs_footer' ) ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'is-single-' . esc_attr( get_post_type() );
    }

    if ( is_customize_preview() ) {
        $classes[] = 'html-is-preview';
    }

    $classes = implode( ' ', $classes );
    echo 'class="' . esc_attr( $classes ) . '"';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the if/else condition from the below function**

```
function brk_root_class( $classes = array() ){

    if ( get_theme_mod( 'brk_preloader', '1' ) ) {
        // start conditon
        if(wp_is_mobile()){ 
            // mobile
            $classes[] = 'brk-preloader';
        }else{
            // desktop, for specific page
            if(get_the_ID()=='1234'){ // 1234 it's a unique page id. WordPress provide id for pages/posts
                $classes[] = 'brk-preloader';
            }
        }
        // end condition
    }

    if ( is_singular( array( 'brs_header', 'brs_footer' ) ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'is-single-' . esc_attr( get_post_type() );
    }
    if ( is_customize_preview() ) {
        $classes[] = 'html-is-preview';
    }
    $classes = implode( ' ', $classes );
    echo 'class="' . esc_attr( $classes ) . '"';
}
```